# kpgu-like application for Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, gpu, acceleration

Is there any [kgpu](http://code.google.com/p/kgpu/)-like application for windows 7?

Answer (score 2):

something like this? http://www.tidepowerd.com/  It is a library for .Net programming

Answer (score 2):

kgpu is a kernel/driver extension, very particular to Linux, and very closely tied to encrypted filesystems (so far).

It would appear that any similar accelerations in windows would need specific driver support from whatever driver is involved with the acceleration (filesystem, network, etc.).  To actually duplicate the encrypted filesystem acceleration that kgpu is presently capable of, Windows' encrypted filesystem drivers (Microsoft code behind the 'BitLocker' name, right?) would need to be adjusted to use CUDA technology.